# Ошибка PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php'; 

try
{
    $result = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name FROM author');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Ошибка при извлечении записей об авторах!';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $authors[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name']);
}

try
{
    $result = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name FROM category');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Ошибка при извлечении категорий из базы данных';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $categories[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name']);
}
if (isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action'] == 'search')
{
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

    //Базовое выражение SELECT.
    $select = 'SELECT id, joketext';
    $form   = ' FROM joke';
    $where  = ' WHERE TRUE';  

    $placeholders = array();

if ($_GET['author'] != '') //Автор выбран
{
    $where .= " AND authorid = :authorid";
    $placeholders[':authorid'] = $_GET['author'];
}

if ($_GET['category'] != '') //Категория выбрана.
{
    $from .= ' INNER JOIN jokecategory ON id = jokeid';
    $where .= " AND categoryid = :categoryid"; 
    $placeholders[':categoryid'] = $_GET['category'];
}   
if ($_GET['text'] != '') //Была указана какая-то искомая строка
{
$where .= " AND joketext LIKE :joketext";
$placeholders[':joketext'] = '%' . $_GET['text'] . '%';
}
try
{
    $sql = $select . $from . $where;
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute($placeholders);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Ошибка при извлечении шуток: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

foreach ($s as $row)
{
    $jokes[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['text']);
}

include 'jokes.html.php';  
exit();
} 
include 'searchform.html.php';
?>
```

> Ошибка при извлечении шуток: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE TRUE AND authorid = '1'' at line 1 [ссылка нажмите искать даст ошибку](http://f22508-hostde6.fornex.org/admin/jokes/?add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в следующем (если это реальный код)

```
//Базовое выражение SELECT.
$select = 'SELECT id, joketext';
$form   = ' FROM joke';  // FORM
$where  = ' WHERE TRUE';
```

Далее же

```
try
{
    $sql = $select . $from . $where;  // FROM
```

`$from` это не `$form`. Кстати, можно просто эхануть `$sql` и посмотреть что вышло.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, глупая ошибка :)